# why MongoDB database connection timedout error in DigitalOcean

Tags: mongodb, digital-ocean

When i tried to get connected to mongodb i got a timed out error,
i have added firewall rules for remote access.
what I did :

Incoming rules => added new rule => custom TCP | 27017 | All IPv4 All IPv6.

the mongo server is running and the user has rules in a specific database.

note : I run it successfully on AWS before with the same steps .

I m sure the error that I got is about the remote access IP .

error :

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connection timed out
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\scrap-source\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:845:32)
    at C:\scrap-source\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:345:10
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\scrap-source\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:9:12)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\scrap-source\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1135:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\scrap-source\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:344:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\scrap-source\server.js:8:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Single',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map(1) { 'My_private_IP':27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  }
}
```

thank you.

Comment: If the database is truly running on your `My_private_IP`, this is inaccessible from outside your VPC|datacenter. You'll need to use a public IP.

Comment: it's runing and working fine , I have used the same steps on amazon aws and it's working , but in digitalOcean I faced this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by following these steps :
show listening mongodb default port by typing

```
sudo lsof -i | grep mongo
```

then allow the remote ip by typing

```
sudo ufw allow from trusted_server_ip to any port 27017
```

the following note exactly fixes my problem:
note : (for example if you are using 0.0.0.0 then allow 0.0.0.0 and 0.0.0.0/0)

now view changes by typing

```
sudo ufw status
```

now open mongod.conf file

```
sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf
```

change

```
. . .
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1

. . .
```

to

```
. . .
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: your_ip

. . .
```

and now restart the server

```
sudo systemctl restart mongod
```

for more info see
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-remote-access-for-mongodb-on-ubuntu-20-04